# how to find a class insider another class using BeautifulSoup in Python 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Now I am using BeautifulSoup to parse data from appleinsider(https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/04/05/next-gen-apple-tv-could-output-120hz-video-beta-code-suggests), I am using this code to get the article conent:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
cnbeta_article_content = soup.find("div", {"class": "row"})
```

now I found this page have many element contains row class. Now I want to get the content named `row` class from class hierarchy `reviews->row->row` , what should I do to make it work? this is the html:

```
<article class="reviews">
      <div class="row">
        <header>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
             
              <h3 class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">&nbsp;</h3>
                      </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="h1-adjust">Next-gen Apple TV could output 120Hz video, beta code suggests</h1>
          </div>
                      <div class="row article-hero-social">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="avatar-link no-gutters">
      <a href="https://appleinsider.com/editor/AppleInsider+Staff"><img loading="lazy" class="avatarLG-article img-circle no-left-gutters" src="https://photos5.appleinsider.com/gallery/appleinsider+staff.jpg" alt="AppleInsider Staff"></a>
      By <a href="https://appleinsider.com/editor/AppleInsider+Staff">AppleInsider Staff</a>
      <span class="hidden-xs"> | <time datetime="2021-04-05T23:47:00+00:00">Apr 05, 2021</time></span>
      <div class="visible-xs" style="margin-left: 66px; margin-top: -18px;"><time datetime="2021-04-05T23:47:00+00:00">Apr 05, 2021</time></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                  </header>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12" id="article-hero">
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://photos5.appleinsider.com/gallery/41208-79854-210405-AppleTV-xl.jpg" alt="article thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12" id="article-social">
          <div class="social-share col-xs-2">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="social-share comments col-xs-2">
              <a href="https://forums.appleinsider.com/discussion/220976" title="Read Comments">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="hidden-xs">7 Comments</span>
              </a>
            </div>
                        <div class="social-share facebook col-xs-2">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/04/05/next-gen-apple-tv-could-output-120hz-video-beta-code-suggests" title="Share to Facebook">
              <img loading="lazy" src="https://photos5.appleinsider.com/v10/images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"><span class="hidden-xs">Facebook</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-share twitter col-xs-2">
              <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/04/05/next-gen-apple-tv-could-output-120hz-video-beta-code-suggests&amp;text=Next-gen+Apple+TV+could+output+120Hz+video%2C+beta+code+suggests&amp;url=https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/04/05/next-gen-apple-tv-could-output-120hz-video-beta-code-suggests" title="Share to Twitter">
                <img loading="lazy" src="https://photos5.appleinsider.com/v10/images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
                <span class="hidden-xs">Twitter</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-share reddit col-xs-2">
              <a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/04/05/next-gen-apple-tv-could-output-120hz-video-beta-code-suggests" title="Share to Reddit">
                <img loading="lazy" src="https://photos5.appleinsider.com/v10/images/reddit.png" alt="Reddit">
                <span class="hidden-xs">Reddit</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-share col-xs-2">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-12"><p>Code strings discovered in the latest tvOS 14.5 beta release suggest an expected next-generation <a href="https://appleinsider.com/inside/apple-tv">Apple TV</a> device will support 120Hz video output.
</p><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="align-center">
</div>
</div><div class="col-sm-12"><p>Current Apple TV models do not incorporate hardware capable of streaming 120Hz 4K content. Aside from internal silicon and operating system limitations, the set-top box's reliance on HDMI 2.0 restricts 4K refresh rates to 60Hz (85Hz at a 16:9 ratio).
</p></div><div class="col-sm-12"><p>According to code uncovered by <em>9to5Mac</em>, however, Apple <a href="https://9to5mac.com/2021/04/05/tvos-14-5-beta-code-suggests-120hz-support-coming-to-a-new-apple-tv-model/">appears</a> to be preparing <a href="https://appleinsider.com/inside/tvos">tvOS</a> software for a model capable of outputting high-resolution video at 120Hz. The publication claims multiple instances of text strings including "120Hz" and "supports120Hz" have been added to PineBoard, the system responsible for Apple TV's user interface. 
</p></div><div class="col-sm-12"><p>If legitimate, the code suggests a next-generation Apple TV will incorporate the HDMI 2.1 specification to support 120Hz output in 4K. 
</p></div><div class="col-sm-12 ad"><div class="primis-ad-wrap"><h2 class="primus-ad-header">Watch the Latest from AppleInsider TV</h2><script src="https://live.sekindo.com/live/liveView.php?s=104577&amp;cbuster=1617674827&amp;pubUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fappleinsider.com%2Farticles%2F21%2F04%2F05%2Fnext-gen-apple-tv-could-output-120hz-video-beta-code-suggests&amp;vp_content=plembed1d41lktxsnmj"></script></div></div><div class="col-sm-12"><p>Apple is <a href="https://appleinsider.com/articles/20/09/01/apple-tv-with-faster-processor-find-my-remote-tech-could-launch-in-2021">widely rumored</a> to unveil a so-called "<a href="https://appleinsider.com/inside/apple-tv-6">Apple TV 6</a>" device sometime this year. The revamped streamer is expected to boast a more powerful processor, enhanced gaming capabilities and a <a href="https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/03/23/tvos-145-beta-code-backs-up-rumors-of-redesigned-apple-tv-remote">redesigned remote control</a>. 
</p></div><div class="col-sm-12"><p>More recent rumbling hint at a launch in the coming months, potentially at Apple's Worldwide Developers Conference <a href="https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/03/30/apple-will-hold-wwdc-2021-on-june-7-through-june-11">in June</a>. </p></div></div>

        </div>
        <hr class="hidden-lg hidden-xs">
                  <aside class="col-sm-12 inline-disclaimer"> 
    <p>
        <em>AppleInsider has affiliate partnerships and may earn commission on products purchased through affiliate links. 
        These partnerships do not influence our editorial content.</em>
    </p>
</aside>
              </div>
    </article>
```

I want to get this:

[image]

Comment: Please share an example of the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I would instead target the `p` tags within parent with class "`reviews`" and then filter out the final disclaimer paragraph (or not if you wish to keep).

This retrieves the main article text which you could use `join` on for example.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get('https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/04/05/next-gen-apple-tv-could-output-120hz-video-beta-code-suggests')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
pprint(' '.join([i.get_text() for i in soup.select('.reviews p:not(.inline-disclaimer p)')]))
```